# MinGW cannot find -lglfw3_d

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw-w64

I'm newbie in OpenGL and C++ and now I'm trying to run some example code. On build I have this fail:
(I have Windows 8 x64 machine, CLion and MinGW)

> C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot find -lglfw3_d

This is my CMakeList

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (superbible7)

LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

# Second, for multi-config builds (e.g. msvc)
foreach( OUTPUTCONFIG ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES} )
    string( TOUPPER ${OUTPUTCONFIG} OUTPUTCONFIG )
    set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin )
    set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )
    set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )
endforeach( OUTPUTCONFIG CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES )

find_package(OpenGL)

set (CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "_d")

if(WIN32)
    set(COMMON_LIBS sb7 optimized glfw3 debug glfw3_d ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
elseif (UNIX)
    find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
    pkg_check_modules(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
    set(COMMON_LIBS sb7 glfw3 X11 Xrandr Xinerama Xi Xxf86vm Xcursor GL rt dl)
else()
    set(COMMON_LIBS sb7)
endif()

set(COMMON_LIBS ${COMMON_LIBS} ${EXTRA_LIBS})

add_library(sb7
        src/sb7/sb7.cpp
        src/sb7/sb7color.cpp
        src/sb7/sb7ktx.cpp
        src/sb7/sb7object.cpp
        src/sb7/sb7shader.cpp
        src/sb7/sb7textoverlay.cpp
        src/sb7/gl3w.c
        )

set(RUN_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

set(EXAMPLES
        alienrain
        basicfbo
        bindlesstex
        blendmatrix
        blinnphong
        bumpmapping
        clipdistance
        csflocking
        compressrgtc
        cubemapenv
        cubicbezier
        cullindirect
        deferredshading
        depthclamp
        dflandscape
        dispmap
        dof
        envmapsphere
        equirectangular
        fontdemo
        fragcolorfrompos
        fragmentlist
        grass
        gsculling
        gslayered
        gsquads
        gstessellate
        hdrbloom
        hdrexposure
        hdrtonemap
        hqfilter
        indexedcube
        indirectmaterial
        instancedattribs
        julia
        ktxview
        linesmooth
        mirrorclampedge
        movingtri
        msaanative
        multidrawindirect
        multiscissor
        multiviewport
        noperspective
        normalviewer
        objectexploder
        ompparticles
        packetbuffer
        perpixelgloss
        phonglighting
        polygonsmooth
        prefixsum
        pmbfractal
        pmbstreaming
        prefixsum2d
        programinfo
        raytracer
        rimlight
        sampleshading
        # sb6mrender
        sdfdemo
        shadowmapping
        shapedpoints
        simpleclear
        simpletexcoords
        simpletexture
        singlepoint
        singletri
        sparsetexture
        spinnycube
        springmass
        ssao
        starfield
        stereo
        subroutines
        tessellatedcube
        tessellatedgstri
        tessellatedtri
        tessmodes
        tesssubdivmodes
        toonshading
        tunnel
        wrapmodes
        )

find_package(OpenMP)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()

foreach(EXAMPLE ${EXAMPLES})
    add_executable(${EXAMPLE} WIN32 src/${EXAMPLE}/${EXAMPLE}.cpp)
    set_property(TARGET ${EXAMPLE} PROPERTY DEBUG_POSTFIX _d)
    target_link_libraries(${EXAMPLE} ${COMMON_LIBS})
    if(MSVC)
        configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/templates/vs2013.vcxproj.user.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXAMPLE}.vcxproj.user @ONLY)
    endif(MSVC)
endforeach(EXAMPLE)

IF (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D_LINUX -std=c++0x")
ENDIF (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")

include_directories( include )
include_directories(extern/glfw-3.0.4/include)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(debug ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(release ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you confirmed that the glfw3_d library is installed?  On my mingw install I only have the glfw3 library, not a debug version and pacman doesn't list a debug version.

Comment: Similar behaviour I have on my iMac machine: 
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/aleksey/Desktop/sb7code-master/cmake-build-debug --target alienrain -- -j 2
[ 83%] Built target sb7
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/alienrain_d
ld: library not found for -lglfw3

Comment: I don't see where you are using find_package for glfw3 in your cmake file but you directly add the extern/glfw-3.0.4/include file to the include directories.  Do you have glfw3 installed in extern/gflw-3.0.4? If so are you including that directory in your lib path?

Comment: After I added find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED) I have another one fail (it pretty big, I hope it'll be not difficult to read it):
...
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3" with any of
  the following names:

    glfw3Config.cmake
    glfw3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "glfw3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "glfw3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "glfw3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

Comment: After I installed glfw from '/extern' directory *.cmake files have been appeared in my 'c:\Program Files (x86)\GLFW\lib\cmake\glfw\' and *.a file appeared in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\GLFW\lib\'